# How to execute a Begin-End Transact SQL statements in Apache nifi?

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I am trying to execute an SQL statement with Begin - End and Cursor in between using Execute SQL processor in Apache Nifi. But this is throwing an error telling "Unable to execute SQL select query". How can I execute transact SQL statements in nifi? Which processor is best suited for this?

Below is the SQL code snippet that I am trying to execute,

```
DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR
DECLARE @stlsn binary(10), @endlsn binary(10), @sequal binary(10), @op char, @upm varbinary(128), @rn numeric, @tg char(10), @ti char(10), @ln char(10), @dv char(10), @cid int

BEGIN
    SET @Cursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM cdc.dbo_SampleDB_CT  

    OPEN @Cursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @stlsn, @endlsn, @sequal, @op, @upm, @rn, @tg, @ti, @ln, @dv, @cid

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @op, @rn, @tg, @ti, @ln, @dv
        IF @op= 1 Execute ('DELETE FROM dbo.NewDB WHERE RNo = '+@rn)
        IF @op= 2 Execute ('INSERT INTO dbo.NewDB VALUES ('+@rn+','''+@tg+''','''+@ti+''','''+@ln+''','''+@dv+''')')

      FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @stlsn, @endlsn, @sequal, @op, @upm, @rn, @tg, @ti, @ln, @dv, @cid
    END;

    CLOSE @Cursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @Cursor;
END;
```

Comment: Better question is why would you want to do this at all? You've managed to roll together a cursor (an updatable one and has `select *` to boot) and dynamic SQL for no apparent reason. These are both the worst things to do in SQL. This could just be two **static** statements: a joined `delete` and an `insert...select...`, or perhaps just an update. What are your table definitions and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Charlieface I am trying to utilize the CDC feature of MSSQL, basically to monitor the changes in source DB and update them to the target DB. Here I am using the cursor to read every row of the _CT table of CDC and based on the `@op` value, I am using dynamic SQL to update target DB. Please let me know if there are better ways to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: What is your table definitions of the `dbo_SampleDB` and `NewDB`

Comment: Let's not forget the fact the OP is **injecting** their "parameters" as well, instead of doing what they should be doing an **parametrising** them.

Comment: Please test that in SSMS before posting.  You've failed to declare a bunch of local variables.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have edited the question to include variable declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This doesn't need to be dynamic at all. You can just do a joined `DELETE` and an `INSERT...SELECT...`.**

You haven't specified your column names so I'm guessing a bit here.

```sql
DELETE FROM n
FROM dbo.NewDB n
JOIN cdc.dbo_SampleDB_CT c ON c.RNo = n.RNo
WHERE c.__$operation = 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.NewDB
SELECT c.RNo,c.tg,c.ti,c.ln,c.dv
FROM cdc.dbo_SampleDB_CT c
WHERE  c.__$operation = 2;
```

I note that you haven't dealt with CDC update rows.